# SQL conditional atomic insertion

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have EVENTS table in my database. A regular insertion of a new event would look like this:

```
private static final String INSERT_EVENT_SQL = "INSERT INTO EVENTS"
    + "(EVENT_ID, AGGREGATE_ID, AGGREGATE_VERSION, EVENT_TYPE, EVENT_PAYLOAD) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?,?,?)";

pst = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_EVENT_SQL);
pst.setString(1, event.getEventId().toString());
pst.setString(2, event.getAggregateId().toString());
pst.setLong(3, event.getAggregateVersion());
pst.setString(4, event.getEventType());
pst.setString(5, event.getPayload());
```

I would like to make this insertion conditional and atomic.

The condition that must be satisfied is that `event.getAggregateVersion()` is equal to the current aggregate version stored in the database plus 1.

The current aggregate version can be calculated from database entries in either of two ways:

1. Find the latest event having the same AGGREGATE_ID and get its AGGREGATE_VERSION
2. Maximal value of AGGREGATE_VERSION among all events having the same AGGREGATE_ID

The version comparison and insertion should be done atomically in order to prevent concurrent insertion of two events having the same AGGREGATE_ID and AGGREGATE_VERSION.

Nice to have: if the insertion fails due to comparison error, it would be nice to have an exception thrown which is not a general `SQLExeption` (in order to handle version violation in a special way)

Comment: `SERIALIZABLE` isolation may aid you; you'll need a retry loop. Otherwise you'll probably need locking.

Comment: And why would you go through all this work instead of just using `SERIAL`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm not very experienced with this technology. By `SERIAL` you mean `SERIALIZATION` isolation level, or something different?

Comment: @CraigRinger, I read documentation related to `SERIALIZABLE` and I'm not sure I want to go into trouble of implementing all the retry mechanisms. I don't expect high traffic in the foreseeable future, therefore I decided to go with locking.

Comment: @CraigRinger, could you comment on this approach: writes to `EVENTS` table will acquire `EXCLUSIVE` lock (in order to allow concurrent reads). Reads will be issued in a standard way, but special reads that need to establish happens-before relationship will also acquire `EXCLUSIVE` lock.

Comment: Totally fine if you don't mind a 1-writer limit concurrency, and very likely the best way to solve it if that's what you need. Instead of acquiring `FOR EXCLUSIVE`, readers can just acquire `FOR ROW SHARE` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably write it like:

```
private static final String INSERT_EVENT_SQL = ""
    + "WITH data (event_id, aggregate_id, aggregate_version, event_type, event_payload) AS"
    + "("
    + "    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    + ")"
    + "INSERT INTO "
    + "   events"
    + "   (event_id, aggregate_id, aggregate_version, event_type, event_payload)"
    + "SELECT"
    + "   *"
    + "FROM"
    + "   data"
    + "WHERE"
    + "   data.aggregate_version = "
    + "      coalesce ((SELECT max(events.aggregate_version)"
    + "                 FROM events "
    + "                 WHERE events. aggregate_id = data. aggregate_id"
    + "                ), 0) + 1"
    + "RETURNING"
    + "   event_id, aggregate_id ;"

    // bind parameters
    // execute
    // get results
```

And check whether you have any rows returned or not; and act accordingly. You should wrap this into a `TRANSACTION` and issue also `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, as mentioned by **Craig Ringer** to avoid concurrency risks. Even if this is just one statement, another process working in parallel (or an external client) might also `INSERT` a row while the `max` is being computed.

I don't full grasp the meanings of your columns, neither why you're doing what you're doing. So, I've made a few assumptions of my own that might *not* do the right thing when seeking the `max`. You probably ought to change the `WHERE`.

See *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c6f2a38f001c4bb24034a8195fab21ca)* for a simulation of how this will behave.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read a bit of documentation and decided to go with locking instead of `SERIALIZABLE`. The locking scheme I want to use is as follows: writes to `EVENTS` table will acquire `EXCLUSIVE` lock (in order to allow concurrent reads). Reads will be issued in a standard way, but special reads that need to establish happens-before relationship will also acquire `EXCLUSIVE` lock. Will this approach be safe enough in your opinion?

Comment: Took me a while to understand what's going on here, but now I can confirm that this solution works.

Comment: You can use `EXCLUSIVE` locks. But this is something you normally try to *avoid*, unless your application is having very low concurrency, and you can really *afford the luxury*. Don't lock explicitly and let the database figure out what it needs to do to have a *consistent* database. And, if a transaction is aborted because something went amiss (one day, it will happen), be prepared to *retry it*.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to have in incrementing column in Postgres is to declare it as `SERIAL`:

```
create table . . . (
    tableId serial primary key,
    . . .
);
```

This is functionally equivalent to `auto_increment` and `identity` in other databases.  You can read about `serial` in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html).

As noted in the documentation, there can be gaps under some circumstances.  However, this is usually the best way to get an increasing sequence number into the table -- and the database does most of the work.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but I don't think that this approach fits my use case. The column titled `AGGREGATE_VESRION` is only similar to auto-increment in context of events having the same `AGGREGATE_ID`. For events having different `AGGREGATE_ID` values, there will be duplicate and out-of-order `AGGREGATE_VERSION` values.

Comment: @Vasiliy . . . That is a more challenging problem.  My general recommendation is to put in the auto-incremented value and calculate the desired values on the fly.